# call service from code behind & script (same/different domain)

Tags: wcf

Can someone give an example of a WCF service in C#, that can be called both from code behind, client script (same domain & different domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give example of a simple service that will have 2 operation contracts.

My service contract

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Sum_WcfService
{
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "JsonpAjaxService")]
public interface IService1
{
    // Default method for WebInvoke is "POST", cross domain requests are made on GET method
    // I will Invoke this operation on post request
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int AddNums(int Num1, int Num2);

    // I will Invoke this operation on get request, from different domain
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string ReturnNum(int Num);
}
}
```

Service Implementation

```
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace Sum_WcfService
{
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public int AddNums(int Num1, int Num2)
    {
        return Num1 + Num2;
    }
    public string ReturnNum(int Num)
    {
        return "Hey, You called ReturnNum with:" + Num;
    }
}
}
```

To make the service callable from different domain, add Factory property as follows:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Sum_WcfService.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Now Config of the project having service

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>  

<!--To make service callable from code behind & script as well-->
<client>
<endpoint address="http://localhost/Sum_Wcf/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"
behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior" contract="SumServiceReference.IService1" name="WebHttpBinding_Well" />
</client>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

<!--Calling from different domain -->
  <standardEndpoints>
  <webScriptEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
  </standardEndpoint>
  </webScriptEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>

 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```

Now add an empty webform to your project, to test your service

add following code in aspx page, include a jquery file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        var Num1 = 10;
        var Num2 = 20;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Service1.svc/AddNums',

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{"Num1": "' + Num1 +'"' +',' + '"Num2": "' + Num2 + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success:" + data.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error: " + result);
            }
        })
    );
```

This is how you can call from same domain client script.

Now to call from code behind, you need to create proxy class of the service. Add service reference to your service.
I added service reference with name "SumServiceReference".
 My code behind is as follows:

```
 using System;
 using System.Globalization;
 using Sum_WcfService.SumServiceReference;

 namespace Sum_WcfService
 {
 public partial class AddServiceClient : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var ServiceProxy = new Service1Client();
         var Sum = ServiceProxy.AddNums(43, 37);
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ShowAlert", "alert(" + Sum + ")",true);
    }

}
}
```

Now let's see how to call from cross domain script. Create a new project add a webform & to it's aspx page add following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var Num = 7;

    $(document).ready(
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://localhost:50345/Service1.svc/ReturnNum?Num=' + Num,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            processdata: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("success:" + data);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Failed to call service");
            }
        })
    );
  </script>
```

Now web.config of your new project(for consuming wcf service) should be:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>

 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Try this code out & report if face any issue.